# RnR: Spree changing page title on static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

So I have a half a dozen static pages such as about us, security, FAQ, etc.  How can I change the page title from the default on these pages?  I've tried a few tricks from just Rails like helper class, @page.title, etc. and it doesn't seem to work.

I saw this question: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/spree-user/title$20/spree-user/I6NSK7hG1Kk/i0kfcqiDIUYJ
But that didn't work either, I get undefined method `title=' for nil:NilClass.

Then I found this:
http://guides.spreecommerce.com/release_notes_0_9_0.html

Doesn't work either.

Seems like it should be simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was simple, the Google Groups solution was:
    <% @controller.title = 'The title you want to use on the page you'd like to use it on' %>

However:
    <% controller.title = 'The title you want to use on the page you'd like to use it on' %>

works just fine; so it was close just a pesky @